# smbclient tree connect failed nt_status_bad_network_name when folder exists

Tags: linux, windows, samba

When i try to enter in a specific folder in windows from samba there is always the same error, can someone please help

with error:

```
smbclient //CLOUDBOX/team/PS -Uuser%pass -c pwd
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.6.25]
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME
```

without error:

```
smbclient //CLOUDBOX/team/ -Uuser%pass -c pwd
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.6.25]
Current directory is \\SBSS-CLOUDBOX\team\
```

Answer (score 15):

I've found the answer you need to put the parameter -D, like this:

```
smbclient //CLOUDBOX/team/ -D "PS" -Uuser%pass -c pwd
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.6.25]
Current directory is \\SBSS-CLOUDBOX\team\PS
```

Comment: Please explain what the -D parameter does. I can look it up, but that defeats the point of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ndemarco It specifies a directory.  You can check what all the commandline flags mean by using `man smbclient`

Comment: By trying to access //CLOUDBOX/team/PS, you're accessing the share "at the wrong level". The share is "team". So you can access //CLOUDBOX/team (probably NOT //CLOUDBOX/team/). If you want to drive into a specific directory, use the "-D" syntax, as mentioned.